# Unique multikey in mongodb for field of array of embedded fields

Tags: mongodb, go, indexing

I have this Document structure:

```
id: "xxxxx",
name: "John",
pets: [
  {
    "id": "yyyyyy",
    "type": "Chihuahua",
  },
  {
    "id": "zzzzzz",
    "type": "Labrador",
  }
]
```

The pets field is not an array of embedded documents (not referencing any other collection).
I want the pets id to be unique across the documents and the document itself, but it seems the mongodb official docs say its not possible and doesnt offer other solution:

> For unique indexes, the unique constraint applies across separate documents in the collection rather than within a single document.
>
> Because the unique constraint applies to separate documents, for a
> unique multikey index, a document may have array elements that result
> in repeating index key values as long as the index key values for that
> document do not duplicate those of another document.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/

I have tried this using mongodb golang driver:

```
_, err = collection.Indexes().CreateOne(context.TODO(), mongo.IndexModel{
        Keys: bson.M{"pets.id": 1},
        Options: options.Index().SetUnique(true),
})
```

but like the docs said, it allows 2 pets of a person to have same ID, while not allowing a pet from a different person to have the same ID compared to the pet of the first person...
is there anyway to enforce this in mongodb ?

Comment: i think you are not wanting a unique document, will one pet own by multi person?

Comment: @suiwenfeng no, one pet for one person